# How to fix a layout position on top when scrolling

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a layout (or tab layout) in the middle of the activity and I want when the user scrolls and this layout reach the top, it stays at the top (replace the toolbar) and rest of the content keep scrolling.
For example, my page looks like this:

```
________________________________
|        custom toolbar        |
|------------------------------|
|                              |
|         some content         |
|                              |
|------------------------------|
|    layout (or tab layout)    |
|------------------------------|
|                              |
|     rest of the contents     |
|                              |
|                              |
|                              |
|                              |
|______________________________|
```

And I want it to be like this after scrolling:

```
________________________________
|     layout (or tab layout)   |
|------------------------------|
|                              |
|     rest of the contents     |
|                              |
|                              |
|                              |
|                              |
|                              |
|                              |
|                              |
|                              |
|                              |
|______________________________|
```

Kind of like the 'My apps & games' page in Play Store app.

Comment: do you want to use some libraries ????? i suggest this one : https://github.com/florent37/MaterialViewPager or you can find another libraries to do this

Comment: @ArashHatami nice library.. thanks for sharing the link...

Comment: @ArashHatami No, currently I don't use any libraries but I will definitely look into that one. Meanwhile any other suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: there are many libraries for this work ..... just search for **Collapsing Toolbar Layout** or you can just use android support library **android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout**

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**1.** Use `CoordinatorLayout` as a root layout.

**2.** Add `AppBarLayout` and `NestedScrollView` as direct child of `CoordinatorLayout`

```
    AppBarLayout     -> Toolbar + Some content + TabLayout
    NestedScrollView -> Rest of the contents
```

**3.** Inside `AppBarLaout`, add child `CollapsingToolbarLayout` and `TabLayout`. Keep `Toolbar` and `ImageView` into `CollapsingToolbarLayout`.

```
   <AppBarLaout>
       <CollapsingToolbarLayout>
           <ImageView /> 
           <Toolbar />
       </CollapsingToolbarLayout>   

       <TabLayout />
   </AppBarLaout>
```

**4.** Add attribute `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"` to `CollapsingToolbarLayout` and attribute `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"` to `Toolbar` for collapsing effect.

**5.** Add attribute `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` to `NestedScrollView` for your content `scrolling` behavior.

**Your final layout structure should look like:**

```
<CoordinatorLayout>

    <AppBarLaout>
       <CollapsingToolbarLayout>
           <ImageView /> 
           <Toolbar />
       </CollapsingToolbarLayout>   

       <TabLayout />
    </AppBarLaout>

    <NestedScrollView>

        <!-- Your content -->

    </NestedScrollView>

<CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Here is an working code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="206dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:titleEnabled="false">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/anim_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="scrollable" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <!-- Your content -->

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Hope this will help~