# Android - How to fix the toolbar on top in AppBar

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Im trying to fix the toolbar when scrolling through the content. Currently the toolbar disappears whe you scroll. I have tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43529353/how-to-fix-a-layout-position-on-top-when-scrolling) but I didn't manage to make it work. So far I have no solution on how to do so. Any help will be appreciated. Here is my XML Layout and a picture of the concerned layout.

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coordinator"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="220dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/pager_most_read"
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="220dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent">
            </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="#0000ff"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin">
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            <me.relex.circleindicator.CircleIndicator
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:id="@+id/indicator"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="48dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/text_selected"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/text_selected"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/gray"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Move that `Toolbar` outside `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: @SatanPandeya I've done that. In that case the toolbar stay at the top but also the whole page from toolbar to the tabs get fixed and don't move. Hope I've been clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while, but I managed to solve it so here is the code:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:title="Title" />

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title">

            <!-- Action bar content -->

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <!-- scrollable content -->

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ... />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```